# Elasticsearch -Search in very big text in a document

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

we ingest log data into Elasticsearch and there's a business requirement to store the whole original input message as a string. In this - so called - original row we must be able to search with wildcards, for partial matches, for exact matches and all this must be done in a case insensitive manner.
Some logs are so large that in cannot be stored as keyword because of the 32K limit, text is the only option. Do you have any idea how the above can be achieved?

The text is a mix of Hungarian phrases, some HEX identifiers, short codes, dates, etc.
I use the hungarian stemmer, hungarian stopwords, lowercase and asciifolding filters in the mapping.

Every hints are highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have expriance with hungarian language but you can try `query_string` or `match` query of Elasticsearch.

First you can defind index mapping with `hungarian` analyzer for `text` field and then you can use below query.

```json
POST index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "text_field",
      "query": "sample text",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

You can follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) documentation where they have given example of all types of query like wildcards, partial matches, exact matches etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This is what i tried so far, but the problem is, that the order of the matching terms is not guaranteed. In our data the same terms my occur many times in the same field in different positions. 
Finally i ended up with a ruby script that takes the original message apart and assembles it again with a special character, and a custom char_group tokenizer that works on that character. So every JSON tag from the original message goes into the inverted index as a whole "sentence".

Comment: e.g. the "sample_text": "some funny words" will be indexed as "some funny words" instead of "some" AND "funny" AND "words" separately. Kind of keyword replica hack...:)